# I get syntax error and missing type

Tags: c++

```
 #include "MyArrayList.h"

 MyArrayList::MyArrayList()
 {
size = 0;   
 }

 NODE* MyArrayList::list_create(void *data)
 {
NODE *node;
if(!(node=malloc(sizeof(NODE))))
    return (NODE*)NULL;
node->data=data;
node->next=NULL;
return node;
}

NODE *MyArrayList::list_add(NODE *node, void *data)
{
    NODE *newnode;
    newnode=list_create(data);
    newnode->next = node->next;
    node->next = newnode;
return newnode;
}
```

On

```
  NODE* MyArrayList::list_create(void *data)
 {


 NODE *MyArrayList::list_add(NODE *node, void *data)
{
```

myarraylist.cpp(8): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

myarraylist.cpp(8): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

myarraylist.cpp(8): error C2065: 'data' : undeclared identifier

myarraylist.cpp(8): error C2761: 'MyArrayList::NODE *MyArrayList::list_create(void *)' : member function redeclaration not allowed

myarraylist.cpp(8): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

Its a linked list

Comment: What *exact* error message did you get from the compiler?

Comment: What is the error message?  What is your code supposed to do?  If you want people to help you fix your code you should provide enough details for them to understand your problem.

Comment: Where is the definition of NODE?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use NULL in C++, but 0. And you don't need to cast a null pointer: any pointer type can point at null. And you shouldn't use `void` pointers in C++ if you can avoid these. In fact, you shouldn't use raw pointers if you can avoid these. And you shouldn't use `malloc()` in C++ if you can use `new`. That said, you must cast the return value of `malloc()` if the left-hand-side of the assignment is not a `void` pointer:

```
node = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE))
```

Comment: Instead of void what should i be using

Comment: Either static or dynamic polymorphism. Program to an interface. `void*` says nothing about the type. Create an interface and call its functions.